# Jenkins Build History not visible after downgrading from 2.7.4 to 1.580.3

Tags: jenkins

We have lost jenkins build history for all the jobs after jenkins downgrade. No related errors in the logs. Any suggestions how I can get it back ?

Comment: I think in this build they changed the API for BUILD_ID. I don't think you can get this back because all your jobs have the new format. It wasn't a backward compatible change. try duplicating a job in the new version, run it once, see the diff between this job information and the old one and try to automate a script to change the diff - again, I think it's only the BUILD_ID format

Comment: I had a backup of old jobs. I copied them still its not working. Do you have a document where the build id changed format is mentioned ?

Comment: I copied some old format jobs and they have the right job format.
But the history is not visible in UI not sure why

Comment: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26520. it's not just the jobs xml configurations, it's the history on the master - do you have build history on the master from the old format?